# jQuery .Last Function Return Boolean

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-selectors

Ok so heres whats going on:

Whenever I click on an image nested in an unordered list, it moves to a different part on the page. But when it reaches the last li, I want it not to move. I am trying to find it out if there is anyway that the .last() function can return a boolean back?

Thanks,
Rohan

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) which returns the last element in the set, for a given set if you have an element you can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/), like this:

```
//abort out at top of the function
if($(this).closest('li').is(':last-child')) return;
```

If the `<li>` is the last in the list, it'll return `true` for `is(':last-child')`.